# pygame graphics grid

Tags: graphics, pygame, blit

Hello, I am new to Python and graphics programming in general. At present I am messing around with creating grids as practice, and I am having problems with getting pygame to put objects on top of the surface window.

Below is my code with comments. I reckon that the problem may be to do with the blit function but I am unsure. Any help would be appreciated. Also, the Python shell does not highlight any exceptions or errors, but the program does not run.

```
import sys, random, pygame
from pygame.locals import *


def main():
    #settings
    boardDims = (20,20) #number of cells on board

    #pygame settings
    cellDims = (20,20) #number of pixels on cells
    framerate = 50
    colours = {0:(0,0,0), 1:(255,255,255)}         

    #pygame
    pygame.init()
        #sets x and y pixels for the window
    dims = (boardDims[0] * cellDims[0],
            boardDims[1] * cellDims[1])
    #sets window, background, and framrate
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(dims)
    background = screen.convert()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()        

    #create new board
    board = {}
        #iterates over x and y axis of the window
    for x in range(boardDims[0]):
        for y in range(boardDims[1]):
            board[(x,y)] = 0 #sets whole board to value 0 
    board[(1,1)] = 1 #sets one square at co-ordinates x=1,y=1 to cell
                     # value 1
    return board


    running = 1
    while running:
        # 1 PYGAME
        #get input
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or \
                (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                    running = 0
                    return
        #link pygames clock to set framerate
        clock.tick(framerate)


        for cell in board:
            #adds cells dimensions and co-ordinates to object rectangle
            rectangle =  (cell[0]*cellDims[0], cell[1]* cellDims[1],
                          cellDims[0], cellDims[1])
            #pygame draws the rectabgle on the background using the relevant
            #colour and dimensions and co-ordinates outlined in 'rectangle'
            square = pygame.draw.rect(background, colours[board[cell]],
                                      rectangle)
        #blits and displays object on the background
        background.blit(square)
        screen.blit(background, (0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()   


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The "return board" statement is exiting your program before any blitting is done.

Also, you can blit the squares directly on the screen variable, ie: you don't need the background variable.